# Bot Framework Using in memory store from Activity Event

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

Trying to store data from ActivityTypes.Event but when trying to access it from the Rootdialog its empty. When I move the code inside ActivityTypes.Event it works fine.

Message Controller:

```
   if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event)
     {        
        using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity))
        {
            var botDataStore = scope.Resolve<IBotDataStore<BotData>>();
            var key = Address.FromActivity(activity);

            var userData = await botDataStore.LoadAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, CancellationToken.None);

            //set state data
            userData.SetProperty("key 1", "value1");
            //get state data
            userData.GetProperty<string>("key 1");

            await botDataStore.SaveAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, userData, CancellationToken.None);
            await botDataStore.FlushAsync(Key, CancellationToken.None);

        }}
       if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
     {     

                    await Typing.SendTyping(activity);
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
     }
```

RootDialog:

```
    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {
            var activity = await argument as Activity;
            string s; 
            context.UserData.TryGetValue<string>("key 1", out s);
            await context.PostAsync(s);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this, when using user data inside event activity, the data is being stored inside the user which is the one who sent the event activity, the solution is to use conversation data instead.

Comment: Please check the updates in my reply to know/compare `UserData` and `ConversationData`.

Answer (score 1):

Before you get state data in your `RootDialog`, please make sure the code snippet for saving state data that you defined in `MessagesController` is executed.

I do a test based on the code that you provided, and I send an `Event` activity from my webchat client, like below:

```
botConnection.postActivity({
    type: 'event',
    from: userinfo,
}).subscribe(function (id) { console.log('you send an event activity'); });
```

I can save and retrieve ***UserData*** as expected.

[image]

***Note:***

In-memory data storage is intended for testing only. For performance and security reasons in the production environment, you can store state data in Azure table storage or Azure Sql Server etc, or implement your own data storage.

***Update:***

- **UserData**: The data that the user has previously saved will be only available to that specified user.
- **ConversationData**: The persisted data will be available to all the users within the same conversation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also flush the dataStore after your call to botDataStore.SaveAsync
using:

```
await _botDataStore.FlushAsync(key, CancellationToken.None);
```

My understanding is that SaveAysn only writes the change to a local cache of the the data store, local in the context of the MessageController. When you call the FlushAsync method it actually 'flushes' those changes out to the bot datastore.

Comment: I have tried using FlushAsync but when I use it inside the Message Activity it works fine but not inside Event Activity

Comment: Can you describe how are you firing the event activity?